# Cant get fonts to work in firefox with heroku + cloudfront + rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

recently switched from asset_sync and s3 to just cloudfront on heroku.
Having issue with getting the fonts to work in firefox.
Have looked at font_assets gem - no luck, also tried rack-cors.
Any ideas/suggestions?

heroku +rails 4.1 + cloudfront

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This post might be helpful to you http://thelazylog.com/posts/resolve-cors-fonts-issue-on-firefox-and-now-chrome-too-with-rails-assets-pipeline

I have to create a fonts.css file and include it into main layout with normal `<link>` tag